# Why does the context of "this" change in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I'm embarrassed to admit how many hours I spent trying to figure this problem out. It turned out that the order of the two lines under the "problem area" comment change the context of "this" when it's used in the prototype addSong function.

```
var PlaylistView = function(config){

    this.config = config || {};
    this.$addSongForm = this.config.addSongForm || $('#addSongForm');
    this.$song = this.config.song || $('#song');

    // problem area
    this.addSong = $.proxy(this.addSong, this);
    this.listenAddSong();
  };

PlaylistView.prototype.listenAddSong = function(){
    this.$addSongForm.on('submit', this.addSong);
};

PlaylistView.prototype.addSong = function(event){
    //Here is where I'm getting different context for this
    var songName = this.$song.val();
    //do some stuff...
    return false;
};

return PlaylistView;
```

When the two lines are in the order shown I get the behavior I want: "this.$song" contains a jquery selector that I had set when initializing the PlaylistView object. However, when I had the order reversed, looking at the inspector in Firefox showed that "this" referred to the actual form in the DOM. 
Why is that?

Comment: No one can be sure what `this` is referring to in your code, since the value of `this` can be changed whatever you want with `.apply` or `.bind` or `.call`, etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because `this.addSong !== $.proxy(this.addSong, this)`.  When you run `$.proxy` and then `listenAddSong` the bound function is used and `this` is your `Playlist` object.  When you reverse the order then the *unbound* function is passed to the listener in `listenAddSong`. You *replace* the unbound function with the bound function in this line:

```
this.addSong = $.proxy(this.addSong, this);
```

So, depending on which function `this.addSong` points to when `listenAddSong` runs, you either get the correct behavior, or the incorrect behavior.